# Plot a partitioned 2D space from a simple regression tree

Tags: r, ggplot2

Take [this](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350-2006/lecture-10.pdf) lecture on simple regression trees as an example. A regression tree is trained and split Y over two parameters.

This allows the author to produce a graph like this:
[image]

Is there any way to produce something similar (including space labels) in ggplot2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, one quick & dirty way could be to modify `tree::partition.tree`, which does that job in base graphics. Here's an example for an iris classification tree:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tree)
ggplot(iris, 
       aes(Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  gg.partition.tree(tree(Species ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, data=iris), 
                    label="Species", color = "cyan")
```

[image]

with

```
gg.partition.tree <- function (tree, label = "yval", ordvars, ...) 
{
    ptXlines <- function(x, v, xrange, xcoord = NULL, ycoord = NULL, 
        tvar, i = 1L) {
        if (v[i] == "<leaf>") {
            y1 <- (xrange[1L] + xrange[3L])/2
            y2 <- (xrange[2L] + xrange[4L])/2
            return(list(xcoord = xcoord, ycoord = c(ycoord, y1, 
                y2), i = i))
        }
        if (v[i] == tvar[1L]) {
            xcoord <- c(xcoord, x[i], xrange[2L], x[i], xrange[4L])
            xr <- xrange
            xr[3L] <- x[i]
            ll2 <- Recall(x, v, xr, xcoord, ycoord, tvar, i + 
                1L)
            xr <- xrange
            xr[1L] <- x[i]
            return(Recall(x, v, xr, ll2$xcoord, ll2$ycoord, tvar, 
                ll2$i + 1L))
        }
        else if (v[i] == tvar[2L]) {
            xcoord <- c(xcoord, xrange[1L], x[i], xrange[3L], 
                x[i])
            xr <- xrange
            xr[4L] <- x[i]
            ll2 <- Recall(x, v, xr, xcoord, ycoord, tvar, i + 
                1L)
            xr <- xrange
            xr[2L] <- x[i]
            return(Recall(x, v, xr, ll2$xcoord, ll2$ycoord, tvar, 
                ll2$i + 1L))
        }
        else stop("wrong variable numbers in tree.")
    }
    if (inherits(tree, "singlenode")) 
        stop("cannot plot singlenode tree")
    if (!inherits(tree, "tree")) 
        stop("not legitimate tree")
    frame <- tree$frame
    leaves <- frame$var == "<leaf>"
    var <- unique(as.character(frame$var[!leaves]))
    if (length(var) > 2L || length(var) < 1L) 
        stop("tree can only have one or two predictors")
    nlevels <- sapply(attr(tree, "xlevels"), length)
    if (any(nlevels[var] > 0L)) 
        stop("tree can only have continuous predictors")
    x <- rep(NA, length(leaves))
    x[!leaves] <- as.double(substring(frame$splits[!leaves, "cutleft"], 
        2L, 100L))
    m <- model.frame(tree)
    if (length(var) == 1L) {
        x <- sort(c(range(m[[var]]), x[!leaves]))
        if (is.null(attr(tree, "ylevels"))) 
            y <- frame$yval[leaves]
        else y <- frame$yprob[, 1L]
        y <- c(y, y[length(y)])
        if (add) 
            lines(x, y, type = "s", ...)
        else {
            a <- attributes(attr(m, "terms"))
            yvar <- as.character(a$variables[1 + a$response])
            xo <- m[[yvar]]
            if (is.factor(xo)) 
                ylim <- c(0, 1)
            else ylim <- range(xo)
            plot(x, y, ylab = yvar, xlab = var, type = "s", ylim = ylim, 
                xaxs = "i", ...)
        }
        invisible(list(x = x, y = y))
    }
    else {
        if (!missing(ordvars)) {
            ind <- match(var, ordvars)
            if (any(is.na(ind))) 
                stop("unmatched names in vars")
            var <- ordvars[sort(ind)]
        }
        lab <- frame$yval[leaves]
        if (is.null(frame$yprob)) 
            lab <- format(signif(lab, 3L))
        else if (match(label, attr(tree, "ylevels"), nomatch = 0L)) 
            lab <- format(signif(frame$yprob[leaves, label], 
                3L))
        rx <- range(m[[var[1L]]])
        rx <- rx + c(-0.025, 0.025) * diff(rx)
        rz <- range(m[[var[2L]]])
        rz <- rz + c(-0.025, 0.025) * diff(rz)
        xrange <- c(rx, rz)[c(1, 3, 2, 4)]
        xcoord <- NULL
        ycoord <- NULL
        xy <- ptXlines(x, frame$var, xrange, xcoord, ycoord, 
            var)
        xx <- matrix(xy$xcoord, nrow = 4L)
        yy <- matrix(xy$ycoord, nrow = 2L)
        return(
          list(
            annotate(geom="segment", x=xx[1L, ], y=xx[2L, ], xend=xx[3L, ], yend=xx[4L, ]),
            annotate(geom="text", x=yy[1L, ], y=yy[2L, ], label=as.character(lab), ...)
          )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic. Thank you for the hard work!

Comment: No noes, thanks to Brian Ripley, the `tree` package author. (I just replaced two lines in his code.)